# UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling native function

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I can succesfully load native library with `System.loadLibrary("")`, but when I call native method from that library, I receive `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, no implementation found for that method.

But this code works in another application, somehow in mine not.

Comment: @blackbelt no, it's MSC library for connecting to a SmartCard

Comment: MSC stays for musclecard ?

Comment: No, its from seek-for-android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you change the packageName in the jni method, it should be `Java_com_example_yourapp_methodname(JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz)` where com_example_yourapp is the reference to your package of the class you call the method.
and after that, did you call `ndk-build` again?

Comment: Oh..I forgot about it..thats sad. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

The method Erik N is suggested fine, but it has some performance impact as the VM need to search a function call with the above signature. Instead you can map the functions with signatures and register them on JNI_OnLoad() function call.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833